# Validate array of objects in AdonisJs 5

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

i'm developing a RestAPI using **AdonisJs 5** and i'm trying to validate the request body to be an array of objects which i don't know what properties it may contain so i don't want to specify any properties.
the payload is something like this

```
{
    "gap": [
        {
            "1": "small"
        },
        {
            "2": "x"
        },
        {
            "a": "king" 
        }
    ]

}
```

where the keys represents something for the business logic.
i tried to do it in a couple of ways and neither of them work

1. by adding empty object to the members function

```
public schema = schema.create({
    gap: schema.array.optional().members(schema.object().members({})),
  })
```

but the result was an array of empty object since adonis neglect any extra data that wasn't provided in the validator schema
2. passing only the **schema.object** without the members function

```
public schema = schema.create({
    gap: schema.array.optional().members(schema.object()),
  })
```

but this results an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is .anyMembers() option.

Read about it here: https://docs.adonisjs.com/reference/validator/schema/object#accept-any-elements

So your solution would be:

```
public schema = schema.create({
    gap: schema.array.optional().members(schema.object().anyMembers()),
  })
```